# Weird Behavior of a Neural Network Implemented in Keras During Training

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have implemented a complex neural network using Keras. The neural network trains normally and reaches up to 100% accuracy during training. However, during the evaluation, the results are very low and the output of the neural network is always 0.

First, I investigated the weights of the neural network and found some nan values. I replaced these values and retrained the neural network. After the training is finished, no nan values exist in the weights anymore. However, the evaluation results are still the same.

Out of desperation, I ran the following to train the network:

```
model.fit(dt[:200],labels[:200],epochs=100,batch_size=10,validation_data=(dt[:200],labels[:200]))
```

Despite all the nonsense in that code, I at least expected to receive identical values for the training and testing sets. But here is what I got:

```
Train on 200 samples, validate on 200 samples
Epoch 1/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 104ms/step - loss: 0.2230 - acc: 0.9650 - val_loss: 7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 104ms/step - loss: 0.0302 - acc: 0.9850 - val_loss: 0.7086 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 104ms/step - loss: 0.0353 - acc: 0.9800 - val_loss: 0.7096 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 104ms/step - loss: 0.0349 - acc: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.7088 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 104ms/step - loss: 0.0298 - acc: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.7097 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 103ms/step - loss: 0.0457 - acc: 0.9800 - val_loss: 0.7065 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 103ms/step - loss: 0.0060 - acc: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.7080 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/100
200/200 [==============================] - 20s 102ms/step - loss: 0.0337 - acc: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.7045 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 9/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 105ms/step - loss: 0.0048 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.7049 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 10/100
200/200 [==============================] - 21s 104ms/step - loss: 0.0020 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.7059 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

The exact same sets are used for the training and evaluation but are returning different loss and accuracy values. Any ideas about what is going on!!!!?

Comment: What happens if you run `model.evaluate` on the same set after finishing training?

Comment: How come you are using the same set as training and evaluation? What kind of data is it?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat the model.evaluate returns the same values in the val_loss and val_acc.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX I'm using the same set to troubleshoot. As the same set is used the same loss and accuracy are expected!!!!

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX He's just doing that to demonstrate that training and validation get different accuracies _even on the exact same dataset_.

Comment: @MohammedPUD Try `keras.backend.set_learning_phase(1)` before `model.evaluate`. I think that should make it emulate the behavior of training, e.g. turning on dropout and stuff like that. If you get 100% accuracy, then you can start looking at what changes between learning phases.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat It returned the same values!  [0.707545280456543, 0.5000000104308129]

Comment: BTW, the predictions of the NN are always zero

Comment: What if you train it, set learning phase to 0, then run one epoch of `model.fit`? Not sure if that will even run, but worth a try regardless.

Comment: Please include model architecture code